# Clicking Left Pedal on Bowflex C6

Tags: crankset, clipless, spd, clicking, pedals-clipless

I have a one month old Bowflex C6 spin bike. I am having a problem where the left pedal (SPD one side and toe cage on the other) clicks a lot when I am riding. I have verified that the crank arm is tight and that the pedal is tight/bottomed out in the crank. I have noticed that the there play between the metal part of the pedal and the bolt piece that engages into the crank. It doesn't happen on the right side. Is there a way to remedy this or do I either live with it or get better pedals?

Comment: When I've had this (on a road bike) it was a sign that the bearings were going bad.  Used to be you could rebuild the bearings, but likely not anymore.

Comment: If it's only a month old, would this kind of problem not be covered by a warranty?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Bearings? I would hope they would last longer than a month ugh. I will have to listen more to the exact location of the noise.

Comment: @DavidW Probably but given the boost in home fitness due to COVID I fully expect a lengthy delay and was seeing it there was an easy fix.

Comment: SPD pedal adjustment is relatively easy, but it will still take some practice. What model pedals do you have? You’ll need either 8 and 10mm thin wrenches, or 7 and 8mm depending on the model.

Comment: Post a photo of the pedal if you can. Could be a simple tightening in the right spot is all you need. Also double-check that it isn’t something innocuous like a strap from the toe clip hitting the crank arm or floor during each revolution

Comment: Does it happen when you pedal by hand? Does it click in the same place in the rotation of the crank? Does it happen when someone else rides the bike? (one person said it was their shoelace tip that was clicking. His wife rode the bike and the click went away). Does it click when pedaling fast / slow / always?

Comment: @salisboss question is now 3 months old, have you had any progress?  If so please share by adding an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that this is common with the C6. If you call Bowflex they should be willing to send you a crank puller and replacement crank under warranty.

Comment: Welcome to the site - good first answer.  Have you had experience with these bikes?   I've posted the progress update request as a comment.

Comment: I do have experience with this bike-- I got it a few weeks ago, and have the same problem.  Some googling led me to some other sites (reddit) where similar issues are discussed. I called Bowflex,  they are sending me a crank puller. So I'm happy to provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @RibaldEddie does it come with a new pedal? Which would be cool - OP is concerned that the pedal is the source of the noise

Comment: @Swifty I don’t know. The conversation didn’t get that far with them. But it’s really just common sense to call the manufacturer.

Comment: Cool, let us know how you get on, you could [edit] in a little update when the clicking has gone away

Comment: @Swifty I’ll have to reach out to them again. I don’t think the clicking will go away without replacing the pedal and crank completely.